# I can't access the admin UI in KeystoneJS

Tags: authentication, keystonejs

I just installed the Keystone yeoman generator and ran the yo keystone command. I went through and entered the email, password, and all the other fields in the set up.

I can run the Keystone App just fine, but when I go to sign in to the admin UI it won't accept my credentials. On the welcome page it tells me that email and password to sign in with so I know I'm using the correct credentials. I checked the User.js model and everything looked fine. I'm new to Keystone and have no idea what the problem could be. I looked through the Keystone docs and for answers elsewhere but have found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed this to be a bug in Keystone. I submitted a pull request ([#1326](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/1326)) to address this issue just a few minutes ago.

<del>I will update my answer as soon as it's merged.</del> It was just merged! :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure eventually that will save someone some future trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Keystone converts any capital letters in an email address to lowercase. If anyone else runs into this issue and has a captial letter anywhere in their email for login, use all lowercase letters and it will then work!

Comment: I would consider this behavior a bug in Keystone. I will submit a PR to Keystone later today to correct this problem.